# How can i access an Azure container via FQDN not IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, dynamics-business-central

I have created a Business central container in Azure named BCTestContainer, now it deploys fine and give me back the details via container logs. I try to access the container by its FQDN namely

```
BCTestContainer.eastus.azurecontainer.io/MYINSTANCEBC/
```

but that gives and error saying cant reach the
page, but if i use the public ip address in Azure as follows

```
<CONTAINER_IP>/MYINSTANCEBC/
```

it seems to work. Do i need to make the FQDN  public accessible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the url through internet , one has to go with public end point networking type .
Your container will be publicly be reachable at `<dns-name-label>.<region>.azurecontainer.io`

Example :When you  specify a custom DNS name label ,then your application is reachable at customlabel.azureregion.azurecontainer.io.
Some times it may take some time to propagate.

When you create the ACI,please checkbelow points:

1. Make sure the image you used works well locally
2. Then you need to expose the right port which your application listen to inside the container image.
3. See if ACI is in the running state

FQDN has access to the 80 port in default. If your application listens to 8080 port, and you expose it.
Then you need to access your application through the FQDN like:
customlabel.azureregion.azurecontainer.io:8080

i.e; when you browse the FQDN you can add the port at the end just like: `FQDN:port`.

**References**

1. [container-instances-quickstart-portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal)
2. [container-instances-Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart#create-a-container)